# Lync 2013 can no longer archive converstations

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, lync, lync-2013

I have Lync 2013 installed on my Windows 7 work machine, which I believe was installed on my machine from day one.  A few weeks ago I upgrade the rest of Office to 2013, I believe it was at 2010 before.

It seems that since then I'm no longer archiving my Lync instant message history.  I've looked at the Options in Lync and "Save IM conversations in my email Conversation History folder" is unchecked and disabled.  In the Windows registry, I've added an IMAutoArchivingPolicy setting under Software/Policies/Microsoft/Communication, it didn't exist before.  I've tried having it set to both 0 and 1, but in both cases the "Save IM conversations in my email Conversation History folder"  setting remains disabled and unchecked.

-Eric

Comment: Are you on a domain?  Sounds like the option was disabled by a group policy.

Comment: I am on a domain, from what I've read that group policy setting is stored in the IMAutoArchivingPolicy setting.

Comment: Update your question to reflect that you are an Administrator on an Active Domain trying to modify the group policy setting.  Because all you indicated was you attempted to change it through the registry which indicates you are not an Administrator of the Domain.

Comment: [This](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/166/t/82232.aspx) and [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/60234383-5b07-46fc-8e8d-7d7a27a93a6c/how-to-enable-conversation-history-in-lync-2013-without-outlook?forum=ocsmanagement) might help.

Comment: I'm not an AD Administrator.  I'm an Administrator on my local machine.  It seems like the archiving stopped when I upgraded to Office 2013.  Until I edited my registry, there wasn't an IMAutoArchivingPolicy setting in my registry which seems to point the Group Policy setting not being set, from my research.

Comment: Confirm with your AD Administrator that there isn't a group policy preventing it from being enabled.

Comment: Apparently it was just a coincidence that it seems to occur about the same time I upgraded my Office to 2013.  Archiving was turned off by Group Policy about the same time.

Comment: Feel free to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was just a coincidence that it seemed to occur about the same time I upgraded my Office to 2013. Archiving was turned off by Group Policy about the same time.

*I just revisited this thread and realized that I didn't really see the workaround that I've been using for this functionality.  There's an open source tool [LyncIMHistory](https://github.com/bujocek/LyncIMLocalHistory) that logs your Lync/Skype for Business History to text files.  It works quite well.  I've been using it for a few years now, I think.  When I upgraded comnputers I moved the contents of my LyncIMHistory folder so I have the history from my previous computer.*